# how to get orphans from a join table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, myisam

Imagine 2 tables, the first one is a list of products (products), the second one a join table between products and another table (categories), called products-categories

products:

```
id   |  name
------------
1       Lorem 
2       Ipsum 
3       Dolor 
4       Sit
```

products-categories

```
product_id  | categories_id
---------------------------
1             3
1             6
4             1
2             2
```

How to get the orphan elements, I mean the elements in no category, so in this case: 3, in a efficient way (+30k records) using MyISAM?

This is somehow like showing all rows that are not joinable, but this syntax seams weird to me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select * from products p 
left join product_categories pc on p.id=pc.product_id 
where pc.product_id is null
```

will return all products in table products that are not found in product_Category. LEft join and where is very fast. 30k records is also very little, so don't worry there.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this in 2 ways:

Using SubQuery:

```
SELECT name FROM products 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM products-categories);
```

or Using JOIN (preferred way)

```
SELECT name FROM products 
LEFT JOIN products_categories ON (id=product_id)
WHERE product_id IS NULL;
```

Better to go with join
sqlfiddle demo : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14ab38/1

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.id from products p left join product-categories c on p.id=c.product_id 
where c.id is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once I used something like following

```sql
select p.id 
from products p 
left join productscategories pc 
where pc.categories_id is null
```